# Python - Django - server - Searches for installed module in wrong version of Python using WinSCP

Tags: django, python-3.x, module, django-views, winscp

when I try to load my server using Django, I get a 'no module named bs4' error. It seems that it searching to for it in Python 2.7 library instead of Python3.6. python 3.6 is in my PATH. I tried looking, but I'm pretty new to this and don't quite understand all the jargon. Can someone 'explain like I'm 5' on how to make it so that it searches Python 3.6 instead of python 2.7? This is the error:

```
    ImportError at /
No module named bs4
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://104.236.89.238/
Django Version:
1.8.7
Exception Type:
ImportError
Exception Value:
No module named bs4
Exception Location:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py in __import__, line 93
Python Executable:
/usr/bin/python
Python Version:
2.7.12
Python Path:
['/home/django/django_project',
 '/home/django/django_project',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:
Mon, 11 Dec 2017 20:58:02 +0000
```

I'm using WinSCP to transfer the files. Everything works perfectly on a local host before I transfer the files and try and run it on a server. Here are some settings on WinSCP. First here is my manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

my settings.py in WinSCP is:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
```

I updated python 2.7 with the missing modules and I got different errors for missing modules. I'm unsure of where I need to make the change to 3.6. The error I'm getting now is 'Templates not found' which to me means that Django is installed to use 3.6 properly, but I'm not completely sure. Thanks so much fo your assistance!

Comment: How are you running your server?

Comment: I'm running It through an online server and using a program called puTTY and WinSCP

Comment: It looks like puTTY on recognizes that I have python 2.7 and python 3.5. I'm using Python 3.6 with Django and path though. Gonna see if I can update the language that puTTY recognizes

Comment: You're sshing into a remote box.  Most likely it's default python interpretter is python 2.7.  It sounds like it's a *nix system.  You'll figure out what kind of system you're logging into and then install python 3.6 on that box.